# Invalid Token '=' in class,struct or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I'm trying to use the `request.Credentials` function and am having the following error after building the solution..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Caching;


namespace com.tortoise.Controllers
{
    public class VebraController : ApiController
    {

        public class HttpHeader
        {
        string username = "foo";
        string password = "foo";

        string url = "www.test.com";

         HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        .
        NetworkCredential myCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username,password);
        string usernamePassword = (username + password);

        cache = new CredentialCache(); 
//Invalid Token '=' in class,struct,interface  member declaration, also for CredentialCache > //Method must have a return type.

            CredentialCache cache.Add(Uri url); "Basic",myCredentials); 
//Invalid token "Basic" in class,struct,or interface member declaration, same with the ')'.

            request.Credentials = CredentialCache cache; 
//Invalid Token '=' in class,struct,interface member declaration

            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + 
//Invalid Token '(' in class,struct,interface or declaration 
Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(usernamePassword)); 
//Invalid Token '(' in class,struct,interface or declaration same for GetBytes. and end of usernamePassword

            // Get the token from the response: 
            string token = response.GetResponseHeader("Token"); 


            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            response.Write (response.StatusCode) ;
 //Invalid Token '(' in class,struct,interface or declaration same for ')'
                }
```

I have included the errors received within the code above. Hopefully they will improve clarity of the issues I have.

Comment: I believe you are writing this code directly at class level, as it appears, it should be inside a method.

Comment: @Selman22

This is what's above:

CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
        CredentialCache cache.Add(Uri url); "Basic",myCredentials);

Comment: Just remove the word CredentialCache. Why not use the code I already gave you in your previous question? This question has already been answered for you...

Comment: @Habib > Could you show an example? I'm only a week into coding in ASP/C#. Thanks

Comment: I have used the code you provided @eddie_cat but there are still errors with it. Hence breaking up the smaller chunks that are still not working.

Comment: In that case I think you are looking in the wrong place for the errors/have changed something trying to fix an error that just caused a new error. Try posting what error you are actually getting before you added the word CredentialCache

Comment: @eddie_cat I have edited the original post with a list of the errors I receive. Of which most are duplicates. I hope it helps explain the issues I still have with the code you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Habib is correct. You need to put most of this code inside a method, you cannot have it all at the class level. Here I've put it inside the constructor for `VebraController`, but depending on the flow of execution of your program you may wish to do it differently. I also removed the inner class you were declaring for HttpHeader as I don't think you really meant to do that. The only remaining compilation error with this code is in the `response.Write()` line. I am not sure what you are trying to do there as `HttpWebResponse` does not include a method definition for `Write`.

Note that you don't need to have include statements for System.Net.Http etc. The ones I have included should be sufficient.

I have declared most of the variables outside the method--this is standard, you declare them as class members so you can use them anywhere in the class. If you only need them in a particular method you can declare them within the method itself. All the "action" parts of your program need to go in a method.

```
   using System;
   using System.Net;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Text;

    namespace com.tortoise.Controllers
    {
        public class VebraController : ApiController
        {
                private string username = "foo"; //class member 
                private string password = "foo"; //class member

                private static string url = "www.test.com"; //class member

                //this is where the constructor starts
                public VebraController() {

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

                NetworkCredential myCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username,password);
                string usernamePassword = (username + password);

                CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache(); 

                cache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", myCredentials); 

                request.Credentials = cache; 

                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + 
                    Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(usernamePassword)); 

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                // Get the token from the response: 
                string token = response.GetResponseHeader("Token"); 

                response.Write(response.StatusCode); //you need to fix this
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean

```
request.Credentials = new CredentialCache();
```

Instead of

```
request.Credentials = CredentialCache cache;
```