# Parse Line and Break it into Variables

Tags: c#, parsing

I have a text file that contain only the FULL version number of an application that I need to extract and then parse it into separate Variables.

For example lets say the version.cs contains 19.1.354.6

Code I'm using does not seem to be working:

```
char[] delimiter = { '.' };
string currentVersion = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Applicaion\version.cs");
string[] partsVersion;
partsVersion = currentVersion.Split(delimiter);
string majorVersion = partsVersion[0];
string minorVersion = partsVersion[1];
string buildVersion = partsVersion[2];
string revisVersion = partsVersion[3];
```

Comment: What problem do you come across? What you mean by not working?Any exception?

Comment: If I replace `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Applicaion\version.cs")` with `"19.1.354.6"` then your code works fine. The file must be different from just `"19.1.354.6"`.

Comment: A file with the exact text `19.1.354.6` is not a valid C# program, so I suspect there is more in that file.

Comment: @EricJ. True. Very unlikely `19.1.354.6` is all there because the extension is `.cs`

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, but if `ReadAllText` fails with a `DirectoryNotFoundException`, it could be because there is no **t** in your **Applicaion**. Perhaps if you described what your problem is rather than just "does not seem to be working"?

Comment: Nothing more in that file. It's actually just a straight up text file. As for an error I'm getting an Invalid Token on the partsVersion = current... On the Equal Sign..

Comment: @GregoryMunson and what does the error say?

Comment: When I hover over the red Squiggly Line under the Equal Sign (=) it says "Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration. That same squiggly is also under the ( and ) brackets of (delimiter) .

Comment: Probably a [dup of this one, then](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26102060/1270789).

Comment: I figured it out.. This was originally to be an Initial Startup need. It was not inside it's own Private Void. By creating a private void along with currentVersion(); at the end of the initialization it now functions as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Altough your problem is with the file, most likely it contains other text than a version, why dont you use Version class which is absolutely for this kind of tasks.

```
var version = new Version("19.1.354.6");
var major = version.Major; // etc..
```

Comment: I didn't know about the Version class. Learn something new every day :) +1

Comment: This makes my solution look mundane, +1 for you

Answer (score 0):

What you have works fine with the correct input, so I would suggest making sure there is nothing else in the file you're reading.

In the future, please provide error information, since we can't usually tell exactly what you expect to happen, only what we know should happen.

In light of that, I would also suggest looking into using Regex for parsing in the future. In my opinion, it provides a much more flexible solution for your needs. Here's an example of regex to use:

```
    var regex = new Regex(@"([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9])");
    var match = regex.Match("19.1.354.6");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Match[1]: "+match.Groups[1].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Match[2]: "+match.Groups[2].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Match[3]: "+match.Groups[3].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Match[4]: "+match.Groups[4].Value);
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No match found");
    }
```

which outputs the following:

```
// Match[1]: 19
// Match[2]: 1
// Match[3]: 354
// Match[4]: 6
```

Comment: Figured out the problem.. Added to the Original Question Comments.. Thanks for your advise..